# Transform a 2D image to mimic a 3D projection on a 3D plane

Tags: matrix, 3d, svg, linear-algebra, projection

According to the SVG spec, you can apply an arbitrary 2x3 transformation matrix to any element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute

I would like to utilize this method to apply a 3D prospective projection to an image in SVG to mimic a 3D projection of the planar image.

I'm using matrix computations in javascript to apply transforms and projections to 3D model-space coordinates (x,y,z) into 2D image-space coordinates (x', y'). But in order to apply the projection to an image or text in SVG I need to project the 3D matrix down to a 2D transformation matrix.

Assuming the image is on an arbitrary plane in 3D model-space, with the image origin defined as a 3D point on the plane, **how do I convert my 3D projection matrix into a 2D tranformation on the image in SVG**?

Answer (score 0):

It's not mathematically possible to use a 2x3 transform to do a 3D perspective projection. That would be what's called a non-affine transform. There's a little more information about that here: http://www.oreillynet.com/xml/blog/2006/09/wherefore_art_thou_svg.html

You could do such a transform on raw data using javascript and display the result as an SVG image of course but you'd only be able to use SVG to display the resulting graphic - you can't start with an SVG image.

Comment: But since the image would itself be on a **plane** in the scene, can't we linearly project the contribution of the z-domain into the x/y domain of the image space?

Comment: You can. You just can't do it with a 2x3 matrix, you need a 4x4 one and SVG natively only does 2x3 matrix transforms.